# Delete link in gridview deleting all row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, sqldatasource

I am facing a problem with my gridview as the Delete link is deleting all the rows where i want to delete one by one. I have record my screen that may exolain more about my problem

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAh0A-UOafU&feature=youtu.be

```
  <asp:GridView ID="FavoritGRDSHOW" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
       DataKeyNames="FavID" DataSourceID="FavoriteGRDView" 
       PageSize="6" Width="600px">
       <Columns>
          <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Image" 
               DeleteImageUrl="~/iconsimg/Delete2.png" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="FavID" HeaderText="FavID" 
               InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FavID" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="AdsID" HeaderText="AdsID" 
               SortExpression="AdsID" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="UID" HeaderText="UID" SortExpression="UID" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="AdsTit" HeaderText="AdsTit" 
               SortExpression="AdsTit" />
       </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FavoriteGRDView" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BeravaConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [FavID], [AdsID], [UID], [AdsTit] FROM [favourite] 
                        WHERE ([UID] = @UID)"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [favourite] WHERE [FavID] = FavID" >
        <SelectParameters>
          <asp:SessionParameter Name="UID" SessionField="UsrNme" Type="String" />
          </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM [favourite] WHERE [FavID] = FavID
```

Is equivalent to this, because *every* record is going to match its own fields:

```
DELETE FROM [favourite]   // deletes all rows in the table
```

You need to specify which ID to delete and pass it as a parameter:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FavoriteGRDView" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BeravaConnectionString %>"

     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [favourite] WHERE [FavID] = @FavID">

     <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="FavID" Type="Int32" />
     </DeleteParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972940.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FavoriteGRDView" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BeravaConnectionString %>"

     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [favourite] WHERE [FavID] = @FavID">

     <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FavoritGRDSHOW" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="FavID" Type="Int32" />
     </DeleteParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```